# Chroot doesn't find `/bin/bash`

Tags: bash, chroot

I would assume the following would work:

```
mkdir /tmp/chrootTest # Create chroot folder.
mkdir /tmp/chrootTest/bin # Create `/bin` in the chroot folder.
sudo mount -B /bin /tmp/chrootTest/bin/ # Bind-mount the real system's `/bin` to the chroot's `/bin`.
sudo chroot /tmp/chrootTest/ /bin/bash # Execute (open) `/bin/bash` in the chroot.
```

However the last command yields:

```
chroot: failed to run command ‘/bin/bash’: No such file or directory
```

I also tried copying `/bin` to `/tmp/chrootTest/bin` and giving it full permissions. However, this doesn't work either.

I would not be entirely surprised to see an error message informing me that `/bin/bash` can't work in its very rudimentary chroot as other files can't be found. However, the error message printed is surprising as the file clearly exists.

Why does this happen? What is necessary to successfully open a bash in a chroot?

Comment: Is `/bin/bash` a static binary, or does it have shared library dependencies (not available in chroot)?  See with `ldd /bin/bash`.

Comment: bind mounting essential system directories insides a chroot environment defeats the security purposes of doing chroot.

Comment: Depending on version, distro, configuration and moon phases of Jupiter, `chroot` uses varying entry points to the VFS. The correct solution has always been to first `cd /` and then `sudo chroot /tmp/chrootTest bin/bash`. Notice the relative lookup of `bash`. Also notice that dependencies of bash still have to be accessible from inside the chroot environment.

Comment: You'll also need `/lib` and perhaps `/usr/lib` and/or `/lib64`, depending on your distribution.  Consider looking at `schroot` (for inspiration, at least).  Its default will bind-mount `/proc`, `/sys`, `/dev`, `/dev/pts`, and you may find you need some of those in your chroot, too.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks! That's a nice command.

Comment: I think the error message is confusing, though. And clearly, it's wrong.

Comment: @UTF-8 No, it's not wrong (there's an ENOENT (file not found) error being raised somewhere, but I don't know why), but it is certainly confusing. I haven't been able to figure out what it is about.

Comment: @UTF-8 Found it. See my answer.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thank you for clarifying that!

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro `chroot` isn't good for added security, there are methods to break out of a `chroot`. It is useful for creating a sandbox for applications though, so you can be more sure what files/libraries/binaries it uses.

Comment: @Centimane Thanks for mentioning that. The reason I set it up like that is that yesterday, a professor mentioned during a lecture I attend that chroot  is used so applications can't break out of a certain subtree of the file system. My intention was to challenge that.

Comment: @UTF-8 I expect you're paraphrasing, but that statement is sort of true. A `chroot` is useful for limiting an application to a certain subtree, but there are exploits to get around it. It can however help you as an admin ensure a certain version of software is used under normal circumstances and is great for encapsulation as a whole (knowing what software/binaries the application uses). So it is meant as a way of directing the application to use only a specific subtree, but not in a way that a user wouldn't be able to get out of.

Comment: @UTF-8 also, if you're getting into this layer of process management you should look into `strace`. It's great for troubleshooting processes not working because it tells you the system calls being made by the process. A skilled linux admin should know the ways of `strace`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If `/bin/bash` is a binary with shared library dependencies, these dependencies needs to be able to be resolved within the chroot.

On my system:

```
$ ldd $( command -v bash )
/usr/local/bin/bash:
        Start            End              Type Open Ref GrpRef Name
        0000115f08700000 0000115f08a0c000 exe  1    0   0      /usr/local/bin/bash
        00001161f6a2e000 00001161f6c88000 rlib 0    1   0      /usr/lib/libtermcap.so.14.0
        00001161bc41e000 00001161bc629000 rlib 0    1   0      /usr/local/lib/libintl.so.6.0
        000011614b1de000 000011614b4dd000 rlib 0    2   0      /usr/local/lib/libiconv.so.6.0
        00001161bd091000 00001161bd35b000 rlib 0    1   0      /usr/lib/libc.so.89.2
        000011612ef00000 000011612ef00000 rtld 0    1   0      /usr/libexec/ld.so
```

In contrast:

```
$ ldd $( command -v sh )
/bin/sh:
        Start            End              Type Open Ref GrpRef Name
        000007ca3c446000 000007ca3c6c6000 dlib 1    0   0      /bin/sh
```

I'm on OpenBSD. The format of the output of `ldd` will be different on a Linux system, but the same essential information (what libraries are shared, and where they are) ought to be displayed on Linux as well.

When I try with a *very* simplistic chroot that only contains `/bin/sh` and `/bin/bash`  ([`doas`](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/doas.1) is OpenBSD's "`sudo` replacement"):

```
$ doas chroot -u kk t /bin/sh
/bin/sh: No controlling tty (open /dev/tty: No such file or directory)
/bin/sh: warning: won't have full job control
$ /bin/bash
Abort trap
```

Notice that I do get a shell (`/bin/sh`), but that `/bin/bash` fails. The error is different from yours but it has, I assume, the same cause. Executing `/bin/bash` directly with the `chroot` command just gives a one-word "Abort" message, again, presumably due to the same issue with libraries.

**Conclusion:** *The chroot needs to contain at least a minimal installation of a system, including device files and libraries that are needed to run the executables within it.*

**Explanation of the "No such file or directory" error on Linux:**

I was a bit confused as to why the error was "No such file or directory" on Linux, so I ran a test through `strace`.

The `execve()` call that ought to have executed the shell returns ENOENT:

```
execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash"], [/* 13 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

... so I thought it was something wrong with *finding `/bin/bash`*.  However, upon reading the `execve(2)` manual, I saw:

> `ENOENT` The file filename or a script or ELF interpreter does not exist, **or a shared library needed for file or interpreter cannot be found**.

So there you go.

Comment: As the answers and comments say, the error of /bin/bash not running has a lot of different reasons. In my case, I noticed from this answer that has dependencies on files in /lib64 which is a symlink to /usr/lib64. On the system where I was facing this issue, I found that the /lib64 symlink was missing so I added it back and now the system boots just fine.

Comment: @HussainAkbar That seems unrelated because the user in the question had issues with running the shell in a chroot directory. They had no issues booting their system.

Comment: Ok. I had multiple windows open to the /bin/bash issue when I added the comment.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure your install system and the Medium you use for chroot have the same arch.

Is The partition you mount to /mnt  your / partition from install System?

I chroot this way.

For ext* filesystem.

`sudo mount /dev/sdxY /mnt`

For separate /boot bios mode partition

`sudo mount /dev/sdzY /mnt/boot`

For efi mode

`sudo mount /dev/sdwY /mnt/boot/efi`

Mount vituelle Filesystems

`for dir in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount --bind $dir /mnt/$dir; done`

For Network acess

`cp -a /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/resolve.conf`

then

`sudo chroot /mnt /bin/bash`

But I only use it with Debian and Ubuntu.

Comment: This is very useful! I was on a Ubuntu VM and my working directory was a mounted windows partition and was getting errors. Moving back to linux worked, and was also a lot faster! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Just modify your example code to the following: (worked for me)

```
mkdir /tmp/chrootTest
mkdir /tmp/chrootTest/bin
mkdir /tmp/chrootTest/lib
mkdir /tmp/chrootTest/lib64
sudo mount -B /bin /tmp/chrootTest/bin/
sudo mount -B /lib /tmp/chrootTest/lib/
sudo mount -B /lib64 /tmp/chrootTest/lib64/
sudo chroot /tmp/chrootTest/ /bin/bash
```